# Multiply Python Launchers and IDLE versions (MacOS)

Tags: python, macos

I have updated Python several times to newer versions and when I intend to open file there are multiply versions of Python Launchers and IDLEs. Is it safe to delete versions I do not need? If so, shall I remove all Python installations via e.g. `brew cleanup`?

[multiple_py_ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyc3v.png)

Comment: If your system version of Python is Python 2, it is generally regarded as *not* safe to delete it, because there may be system components written in Python 2 that will fail if you do.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to delete Python versions that you installed with brew via cleanup, you will however still keep the latest. This should not effect your system integrity (hard to mess with that on MacOS anyway). What could happen is that Code that was compiled for a specific Python Version might no longer run, but as long as you never did that, you should be fine.